# How can I incorporate a slideshow into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, adobe-brackets

I would like to know if you could guide me on making a slideshow for my HTML document. I know that I will need JavaScript, and I already know how to MAKE the slideshow, but how would I make the slideshow able for view in my html document? Here is the code, and I am using Adobe Brackets as an editor:

//////HTML CODE ////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
        <title>Quentrum</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">
                        Quentrum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="Store.html">
                        Store
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="Support.html">
                        Support
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <section>
                <h>----------Slideshow Goes HERE-----------</h>
            </section>
            <footer>
             <p>Quentrum 2015</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

//////// CSS CODE /////////

```
body{
background-color:lightgray;
}
#wrapper{
width:inherit;
}
header{
background-color: white;
clear:both;
height: 50px;
border:solid 1px black;
border-radius: 5px;
width: inherit;
padding-right:195px;
padding-left:195px;
}

header ul {
list-style: none;
}
header ul li{
display: inline;
padding: 115px;
}
header a {
color: #777;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 17px;
}
header a hover:{
color:black;
}
section{
clear: both;
height: 550px;
width: 100%;
border: solid 1px darkblue;
border-radius: 5px;
background: blue;
font-family: Georgia;
}
footer{
width: 100%;
border: solid 1px gray;
border-radius: 5px;
background: lightgray;
clear: both;
}
footer p {
font-family: Geogria;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Thank you in advance!!!

EDIT[I don't think I really need to paste any Javascript code, but please TELL me if you need it, and I'll get it up. For the sake of this when you answer, you can just pretend that the name of my javascript file is "example"
Many thanks.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps extremely simple simply add this code where you want it then there is no left and right links to next n prev if want images same size simply change image size read notes/ comments for further details

```html
<!-- Add below This To HEAD -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add below  this to your style sheet -->
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }

<!-- Add Below this where you want it in your page -->
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>

<!-- 
Add 
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="next number"></li>
to how many images you want or if you dont want any links to change images atall delete this up to indicators
-->     
      
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="firstimg.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="secondimg.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="thirdimage.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="fourthimage.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        
<!-- Add for more images
<div class="item">
        <img src="nextimage.jpg" alt="..." width="460" height="345">
        
If want captions Add like so

<img src="filename.jpg" alt="alt">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>

        -->
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I am having some trouble, the code works great because I can see my pictures, but the problem is resizing the images. I am having a lot of difficulty because when I change the size next to the pictures, nothing happens, and when I change the width in the systle sheet, I still can't get it to fit my section box, whether I type 100%, or however many pixels, is there a certain way to do this? I am new to HTML by the way, so I just added the code you said to put in the style sheet right under my section in the style sheet. Is that okay? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding this to you style sheet

`.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
   width:sizedesiredpx;
   height:sizedesiredpx;
  }`

id this doesn't work then send your full code and tell me the size you want the images to be and ill try fix it for you

Comment: I really think this was a glitch. So I removed all the added code, then readded it and it worked. Thank you very much because that is exactly what I did! Thank you.

Comment: your very welcome glad could help took me a while to configure mine also but got there in the end take a look if you like http://rbgraphix.co.uk/gallery/display/New/slideshow.php (the image on there aint gonna be the images I display this was just for the making of it) mine fetches the img name and caption from a sql dadbase which enables users to be able to upload images

Comment: So now, I have a tiny question, now that my slideshow is incorporated, my background I used to have doesn't show up, the background of the whole website, the one I put in body{}. And my footer text became smaller, and well my navigation bar at the top, the words in it are not centered anymore they are pushed up. Do you know if there is a way to fix this? Or is this because I am linking myself to the bootstrap website stylesheet.

Comment: send me the code and a link to the background image so I can download it and I will take a look and try fix this for you

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the way you want to do it, however there is a built in Bootstrap slideshow option.

Its called a carousel, here is the link for a tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via jQuery.

```
        $(function () {

            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

            setInterval(function () {
                $('#slideshow > div:first')
                        .fadeOut(1000)
                        .next()
                        .fadeIn(1000)
                        .end()
                        .appendTo('#slideshow');
            }, 3000);

        });
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95cxc3vu/)

Comment: Hello, upon looking at yours, it looks good as well, but now how do I link that JavaScript file to my html?

Comment: You can put it within <script></script> tags at the bottom of your page.

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved the footer and navigation issue for you I believe simply download this new css file and replace it with current bootstrap.css

[Link to Bootstrap CSS Click To Download](http://rbgraphix.co.uk/css/bootstrap.css) 
Check your css as I noticed it says lightgray not lightgrey

also add this to your current main.css

```
footer p {
font-family: Geogria;
margin-left:30px;
font-size:16px; /* Font Size You Want */
}
```

and regarding you background color change it to lightgrey and should work ok once done these steps

Comment: Okay, thank you for this I will try it, my html editor allows lightgray, is there much of a difference? I just want to know cause I never made a website before and I would like to know if the browser reads it differently? Here in the US we spell gray, g-r-a-y I know probably in the UK and other parts gray is spelled g-r-e-y. But thats okay, I will try the new bootstrap and see how that works.

Comment: Im not sure on the difference other than the shade of colour but when using gray in your code it didn't display the colour for me  when I changed it to grey it showed personally I use colour hex code instead of the colour name as you can be more precise on shades the hex for gray is #808080  and browsers read them correctly if you want to use hex code you can find colour hex codes at http://www.color-hex.com/  by simply entering a colour name and it will show you the colour hex code for different shades

Comment: Oh, thank you, I understand. So now, I was wondering, can I refer to the bootstrap css only in the place I have my slideshow? Instead of in the <head> function?

Comment: ye simply add the .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img  lines to the bootstrap css rather than having in the head or your main.css

Comment: Sorry, that I am STILL asking questions, but just to make sure, how do I add that to the bootstrap css? It is a link. Or do I just go to <section> because that is where I am putting it and just put it like this:  <section> <style> .carousel-inner > .item> img </style> <section> ? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh you haven't downloaded it? if you go to the link I gave you in the browser and download it and the you can edit the file and add what you need to it as well you can add your contents of main.css to same file instead of having 2 separate css files

Comment: Oh so this is a download! Okay, I see, now I will download it and get back to you soon!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of slideshow are you looking forI am currently create one using jquery and php

a preview of the slideshow can be found at http://rbgraphix.co.uk/gallery/display/New/slideshow.php

at the moment it is not automatic but I am in the process of making it this way and also has an upload page /upload.php and a delete page (currently in coding (for admin users)

Comment: Hello, I would like a slideshow that simply loops and thats all. I will look at all of the different answers, thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome I believe  you can do this with the bootstrap carousel just remove the <!-- Left and right controls -->  I will be probably using this to make mine auto slide just without the sidebar buttons as I wish to integrate these separately with my design will be trying once created the delete page